# findPreference returns NULL on the legit pref name

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

It's so frustrating. Why I'm getting null on the preference retrieval in my PreferenceActivity class in the following code?

```
private void setupSpecialPrefClickListener(SettingsSystem settingsSystem) {
    Map<String,?> keys =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getAll();
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if( key.startsWith("d_")) {
            Preference p = findPreference((CharSequence)key);
            //p == NULL!!!!!
                            p.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        }
    }

}
```

The pref name found and passed is perfectly legit name of existing pref ("d_lightSensorLimit" - the exact one matched first in the Map and causing the exception). And it was extracting perfectly fine by the plain text string in the constructor before. This method is called from the constructor too (replaced the huge list of entries there with call of this method):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_system);  
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    setupSpecialPrefClickListener(this);
}
```

By people request here is the relevant excerpt of the settings_system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<Preference
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:dialogTitle="Night mode on lux (0-disable)"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:key="d_lightSensorLimit"
    android:layout="@layout/pref"
    android:title="Automatic nightmode" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'm targeting 2.1 so is the deprecated method in use. And it was working perfectly fine before.

Comment: So, what is the value of key, and can you show your preference xml? This is too vague. Also, please post your entire onCreate method.

Comment: What version are you targeting? I note that the findPreference in PreferenceActivity is deprecated - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra It's only deprecated because Google wants you to use PreferenceFragment instead, but it still works just fine on all versions of android.

Comment: You mention that that is the 'relevant excerpt' of the settings_system.xml, but are you perhaps putting that preference into a separate preference category? findPreference **only** finds preferences that are directly children of the PreferenceScreen. It won't find preferences in nested groups or screens. Otherwise I think the code is fine.

Comment: Still no go. My only clue is that getAll() does not retrieve my custom preferences (as you can see, I'm using the generic Preference tag in the XML prefs definition file). This prefernce acts as a simple button, calling the user input activity on click. Anyone, please?

Comment: @Tim: It appears there's new data about finding preferences within Preference Groups.  According to the PreferenceGroup docs [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)] "This will recursively search for the preference into children that are also PreferenceGroups."